# Playing sound after certain interval in soundpool

Tags: android, soundpool

Iam trying to play sound  using soundpool with certain delay. How can i delay the sound without delaying the system because as i will write delay code then whole sysytem will be delayed and stop and pause button will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your soundpool.play() to a separate thread, or even better create a service that handles the entire sound pool for you and method calls from the activity to trigger play events when needed.

Comment: Yeah i tried service too but my problem is i have to put delay between the sounds and i have multiple sounds to play . Iam stopping the service by clicking stop button from main activity . I was using thread.sleep for delay but as because of thread.sleep, stop  button is not triggering.